# My backend calls itself via API - works fine with flask webserver, hangs with gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

My application is a Flask backend that serves a SPA frontend react app. The backend actually consists of 2 layers called api and bff. All three run from the same process.

The frontend calls the bff which sometimes makes calls to the api layer - a REST api call, not an internal function call. E.g. the backend does requests.get("http://localhost/api/foo").

When I run my app locally using flask webserver, it works absolutely fine.
When I run my app locally using gunicorn, the calls from the frontend to the backend work fine but the backend calls to itself do not.

I don't understand what is different. Here's a typical printout; my print debug message showing the URL that is being called followed by the gunicorn critical worker death message 30 seconds later. I note that the session cookies are actually wiped at this point so the worker is actually dieing. Why?!

```
http://localhost:5000/api/requests/
[2020-05-20 21:30:12 +0100] [769] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:771)
```

I'd be super grateful for any help here, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me why I wasn't seeing any errors but it looks there was an unhandled error. I fixed that and this now works. When I ran locally, i was using a slightly different config which didn't experience the unhandled error and so it wasn't an equivelant scenario.